# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS Undefined in Cloud Run Container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to log into gcloud from inside of a Cloud Run container. I know this is not the best thing to do, but it is what the situation requires.

When accessing the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in my entrypoint script inside of the container

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
gcloud config set project "$PROJECT_ID"
```

authenticatin fails because GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not set to anything. It is empty; undefined. No path.

These are the commands I am using to deploy (with the env vars set obviously):

```sh
gcloud builds submit --tag "gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/tester"
gcloud run deploy --image "gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/tester" --service-account "testerkey@${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --platform managed
```

I have also tried to deploy without specifying the service account to use the default one, and that does not seem to work either.

Any advice appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services running inside Google services do not use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, they have a metadata server that provides the token for the service account without injecting the private key. [Defined here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values#vm_instance_metadata)

You can just use gcloud without using the `gcloud auth activate-service-account` command

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. I should have known that!